# Adding image next to text in select2 sends an object

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I'm trying to add image next to text using select2, here is my code :

```
$(".js-example-templating").select2({
  templateResult: formatState,
  templateSelection: formatState
});
function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
  var $state = $(
    '<span><img src="/dist/images/icons/icon_skypeprofile@2x.png" class="img-flag" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
  );
  return $state;
};
```

I got [Object Object] in the select menu :
[image]
And when i select one of the users i got what i want :
[image]

I can't find my mistake!

Comment: try a `console.log(state)` so that you can debug it and see the desirable attribute to use .

Comment: the console.log($state) shows " [Object Object]", but when i use google chrome breakpoints i can see that $state is filled up correctly with the span i want

Comment: I don't know why, it's working for the selected object, and not for the list even if i m calling the same function for templateResult and templateSelection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my mistake, i had to convert the jquery object to string, before sending it:

```
return $state.prop('outerHTML');
```